# Flutter: Check if key exist in list of [{"key": "value"}]

Tags: list, flutter, dictionary, dart

Hi there 1month and still learning Dart/Flutter, Any way to check if "key" exists in [{"key": "value"}]?
I came from Javascript and python environment so I really have no idea what this thing called I just know it's a sort of list

so here's my JSON

```
var example = [
  {
    "name": "Store1",
    "products": []
  },
  {
    "name": "Store2",
    "products": []
  },
  {
    "name": "Store3",
    "products": []
  },
  {
    "name": "Store4",
    "products": []
  }
]
```

So I'm trying to access it with like this

```
var organizedCart = [];
for (var i = 0; i < example.length; i++) {
  if (!organizedCart[0].contains(example[i]['name'])) {
    organizedCart.add(
      {
        "name": "${example[i]['name']}",
        "products": [],
      },
    );
  }
}
```

The goal of the condition is to avoid adding an existing "name",
So basically I want to add a {} inside a list if the organizedCart does not contain the condition given

Thanks in advance!

[demo](https://dartpad.dev/9b0fc96bb64113cbdb1da34466abbbd1?)

Comment: what are you getting as a result now?

Comment: Uncaught Error: RangeError (index): Index out of range: no indices are valid: 0

Answer (score 0):

Try changing your for loop to `for (var i = 0; i < example.length - 1; i++) {`

Rest seems to look correct.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `Set` instead of a `List`. If you use [`LinkedHashSet`](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.12.4/dart-collection/LinkedHashMap-class.html) you can define what should be seen as equal elements.

So we can then add all our elements to this new `LinkedHashSet` which will automatically ensure that elements is added in such a way that we are only adding the `Map` if our `Set` does not already contain a `Map` with same `name` value.

```
import 'dart:collection';

void main() {
  final example = [
    {"name": "Store1", "products": <Object>[]},
    {"name": "Store2", "products": <Object>[]},
    {"name": "Store2", "products": <Object>[]},
    {"name": "Store3", "products": <Object>[]},
    {"name": "Store4", "products": <Object>[]},
    {"name": "Store4", "products": <Object>[]}
  ];

  final organizedCart = (LinkedHashSet<Map<String, Object>>(
          equals: (a, b) => a['name'] == b['name'],
          hashCode: (o) => o['name'].hashCode)
        ..addAll(example))
      .toList();

  print(organizedCart);
  // [{name: Store1, products: []}, {name: Store2, products: []},
  // {name: Store3, products: []}, {name: Store4, products: []}]
}
```

I should note that what you should properly do is stop using `Map` as objects and instead actually define a class called e.g. `Store` which has the fields `name` and `products`. By doing so, we can add the comparison logic here and also make the solution a lot more type safe.

I know JavaScript developers really love using `Map` for everything but it is really a bad behavior ;)

**Update:**

Here is an example using a `Store` class but where we use the same trick with a `Set`:

```
class Store {
  final String name;
  final List<Object> products;

  Store({required this.name, required this.products});

  @override
  bool operator ==(Object other) => other is Store && other.name == name;

  @override
  int get hashCode => name.hashCode;

  @override
  String toString() => '$name have these products: $products';
}

void main() {
  final example = [
    Store(name: 'Store1', products: []),
    Store(name: 'Store2', products: []),
    Store(name: 'Store2', products: []),
    Store(name: 'Store3', products: []),
    Store(name: 'Store4', products: []),
    Store(name: 'Store4', products: []),
  ];

  final organizedCart = {...example}.toList();

  print(organizedCart);
  // [Store1 have these products: [], Store2 have these products: [],
  // Store3 have these products: [], Store4 have these products: []]
}
```

Since our `Store` implements its own `==` and `hashCode` we can just use do `{...example}` to create a new `Set` where we add all `Store` objects from `example`.

Comment: Hey there thanks for this! still learning dart and map is really confusing for me tbh... and I can't find a good source of dart map/list tutorial which tackles everything from scratch .. anyway thank you!

Comment: `Map` should be used where you have a defined type for `key` and `value`. When you begins to have multiple types of `value` (or `key`) in your `Map`, you are properly doing something wrong and should think about using a `class` instead. The problem is that if you `Map` contains multiple types, the Dart analyzer cannot help you finding type errors statically and you do therefore risk having runtime errors.

Comment: Thanks, I'll find a way to study this from scratch :)) Godbless

Comment: @SuperKola I guess you have looked at the official language tour: https://dart.dev/guides/language/language-tour#maps and https://dart.dev/guides/language/language-tour#lists